# Best place to download or purchase shapefiles for Louisiana Parish?

Tags: data, census, united-states, tiger

I am looking for shapefiles to either download or purchase for the BEAUREGARD Parish in Louisiana. I have been able to find files for the Townships and Sections but I am in desperate need of a shapefile with TRACTS. If anyone know where I could obtain something like this it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: TIGER 2013 TRACTS US  ftp://ftp2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2013/TTRACT/

Comment: Thank you for your post. Unfortunately this does not seem to be the tracts that I am looking for in Beauregard Parish. I appreciate your help though. Thank you.

Comment: it is in here somewhere ftp://ftp2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2013/TRACT/ might be better when the web interface is up and running. http://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/tiger-line.html

Comment: Thanks again. Unfortunately I am looking for the subdivided tracts that are divided within each section of the townships. I may be wrong, but I do not think that this is what this is. I really appreciate your help though and anything else that you can think of would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The FIPS county code for Beauregard Parish, Louisiana is 22011. Why is this important? TIGER files in the ftp server are organized for administrative boundaries by FIPS county codes.

Also, subdivided tracts within townships (Census Bureau recognizes them as Places or CDP's) sounds like a description of Partial Census Tracts or "All Census Tracts (or parts) fully within/partially within ..." such and such.

As far as I know, one way to create partial census tract shapefiles is to use Topological Face shapefiles and dissolve up by Tract and by Place so that the result is a collection of unique Tract+Place boundaries.

For instance, if you want the latest release of version of Faces for 2013, it is [here](ftp://ftp.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2013/FACES/).

If you want to use this shapefile to join with Census 2010 SF1 or SF2 data, you must use faces from [2010](ftp://ftp.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2010/FACES/).

To create the linkable GEOID variable according to the [methodology book](http://www.census.gov/prod/cen2010/doc/sf1.pdf) and some results from American FactFinder, you should concatenate the ID fields in the following order: STATE-PLACE-COUNTY-TRACT.

I wish you luck, and remember your FIPS county code.